# What is a "shear of light"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

A line from the movie *The Road*:

> There was a **long shear of bright light**, then a series of low concussions.

With the noun **shear** being a tool, I can't imagine what a **shear of light** would look like. I also thought it might figuratively refers to something shear-shaped, but still find it hard to conjure up the image. What does the word **shear** mean here?

Comment: Perhaps looking like a single blade of a pair of shears?

Comment: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1731/8397/products/A1ewkgqh76L._SL1500_600x.jpg?v=1500278044

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So like rays of light crossing paths?

Comment: I think it's just a metaphorical image, like the light is shearing something, not that the light literally looks like a shear.

Comment: Or possibly it looked like a flat  layer of  light against the light of the sky.

Comment: Edit of comments is broken on my browser.    No, not crossing paths, just a single shear (blade) from a pair of shears.  A sword-like ray.

Comment: Could it have been a typo in the original MS? `long spear of light` would make more sense to me, or even `smear`. I wouldn't swear to it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [blog](http://scienceblogs.com/builtonfacts/2009/03/24/the-road/) I found from the context:

> McCarthy’s work is nothing if not spare and meditative, and
>   essentially no detail about the catastrophe is given.

Perhaps the author intended this description to convey *ideas* about what had happened. The Oxford dictionary has a meaning of [shear](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shear)

> 2 Break off or cause to break off, owing to a structural strain.
>
> *no object* ‘the gear sheared and jammed in the rear wheel’
>
> *with object* ‘the left wing had been almost completely sheared off’

These are not literal meanings here. The author may be using the word **shear** as a metaphor for a catastrophe that is not described in detail. It hints at the word **sheer** too, which conveys the idea of a break point.